# Redefining a variable inside a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a problem with getting an 'undefined' error in my code or, my variable being incorrectly redefined. I am trying to redefine a variable that is inside a loop each time the loop is executed. But the problem is that either (when my variable is defined outside the loop) i get a 'variable is undefined' error, or the variable does not change and/or is reset to zero when the loop is reinitialized.

```
def game():
    scorePlayer = 0
    scoreAI = 0 #If I define it here I get the latter of the two errors explained.
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    print ("Your score is ", scorePlayer, ". Your opponent's score is ", scoreAI, ".") #This is where it tells me it is referenced before defined if I define outside the loop.
    print (" ")
    print ("Rolling...")
    print (" ")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You have rolled a ", number, ".")
    print (" ")
    print ("Player, would you like to hold (enter 'hold') or roll (enter 'roll')?")
    print (" ")
    decide = raw_input(" ")
    if decide == 'hold':
        print (" ")
        scorePlayer = tempScorePlayer + scorePlayer
        gameAI()
    elif decide == 'roll': #changed to elif
        print (" ")
        if number == 1:
            print ("You have rolled a 1. You will not gain points from this turn.")
            print (" ")
            tempScorePlayer = 0
            gameAI()
        elif number >= 2: #changed to elif
            print (" ")
            tempScorePlayer = number + tempScorePlayer
            game()
    if scorePlayer >= 100:
        winPlayer()
```

I have tried defining the variables everywhere else so that they wouldn't interfere with the loop and still couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Inside a function, you are only working with *local* variables. You can access values for global variables but you cannot change them on the global (outside the function) scale without declaring them global at the start of the function.

Comment: I don't see any loops here...? Have you had a look at `global`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def game():
    scorePlayer = 0
    scoreAI = 0 #If I define it here I get the latter of the two errors explained.
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    print ("Your score is %d. Your opponent's score is %d."%(scorePlayer, scoreAI)) #This is where it tells me it is referenced before defined if I define outside the loop.
    print (" ")
    print ("Rolling...")
    print (" ")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You have rolled a %d.", number)
    print (" ")
    print ("Player, would you like to hold (enter 'hold') or roll (enter 'roll')?")
    print (" ")
    decide = raw_input(" ")
    if decide == 'hold':
        print (" ")
        scorePlayer += tempScorePlayer
        gameAI()
    if decide == 'roll':
        tempScorePlayer = 0
        print (" ")
        if number == 1:
            print ("You have rolled a 1. You will not gain points from this turn.")
            print (" ")
            gameAI()
        if number >= 2:
            print (" ")
            tempScorePlayer += number
            game()
    if scorePlayer >= 100:
        winPlayer()
```

I changed the tempScorePlayer variable, setting 0 at it by default.

Note: `tempScorePlayer += number` it's equals to `tempScorePlayer = tempScorePlayer + number`